# Chrome extension- Inject script on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am a newbie to extensions. i want to create a extension, when clicked on the icon it should open up the www.gmail.com, input my user name and password and login automatically,click on the first mail. Your help is highly appreciated. I tried many things like chrome inject api but did't work out.

Comment: The official [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) and the official [sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) are excellent and should be studied before writing an extension.

Comment: we can't help if you dont show what you tried and didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in comments, go have a look to documentation sample codes, it's a good start.

For your extension you should do something like this :

1. Open a tab with the gmail.com url.
2. in the callback, inject a content script in the newly created tab
3. In the content script put the login and the password in page input and then simulate a submit button click.

Try to do this for a first try. When you get it work, You can try to open the latest email received. Look for tabs and runtime message api to send data or event between injected scripts and background script.